# How to handle window visibility when in recent apps view

Tags: flutter

I want to hide the app preview of a single specific screen in recent apps when the user leaves the app. Like if the user is on a secure payments page but pressed recent apps or changes the app to another one then the preview we get in-app switcher (or recent apps) should be hidden.

The Visibility widget only visibility widgets of the app.

Comment: ```getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)```?

Comment: Yeah. That's it

Comment: It disables Screenshots & preview for the whole flutter app, is there a way to use it only on 1 screen?

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible now. Because Flutter uses just one host Activity. So setting that one that Activity will affect the who Flutter View

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As suggested by [Akora Ing. DKB](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814724/akora-ing-dkb), we have to write platform code to disable previews & screenshots for a specific platform. [(Reference video)](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iVNTTX5GrUc&list=PLR2qQy0Zxs_UdqAcaipPR3CG1Ly57UlhV&index=125&t=0s)

For Android, we have to add `getWindow().addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)` for flutter activity. This disables previews & screenshots for the whole flutter view. To only disable a single screen we'll need another flutter activity.

I don't know about iOS but on Android, we can create multiple flutter activities. Problem is, the FlutterActivity will automatically start the main Dart entry-point. So if we want to use a different entrypoint we would have to duplicate the FlutterActivity and give it a custom Delegate which starts the other entry-point in its onCreate().

I'm sure this answer would not be completely right, but it would be helpful for someone.